# what adjective ending in -y best describes someone who thinks they're the centre of the universe?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

I'm writing an article about the seven writing trolls. All of them end in -y, e.g. Cocky, but I"m struggling with one, ie the writer who is unwilling/unable to empathise with the reader and focuses instead on themselves.

Comment: With reference to being selfish I though of 'Selfy'!

Comment: Even the original Disney dwarfs had one whose name didn't end in -y. You could use *Hub* (unless you think that's too subtle).

Comment: Well, obviously it's *my* Universe.

Comment: Solly would be a decent name.

Comment: ...short for Solitary?

Comment: If you can't find a word ending in "-y" it's okay to break the rule once. Think Doc from the "Snow White" film. Your last troll can name itself out of theme, that's how self-centered it can be.

Comment: Perhaps [*Autology*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/autology) or *Autobiography*??

Comment: Hmm.. *egotisty*?

Comment: How many letters?

Answer (score 1):

[*Haughty*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haughty):

> having or showing the insulting attitude of people who think that they are better, smarter, or more important than other people

It implies more distance than mere "pride," but if you still think that's too close to *Cocky*, there are two that perhaps imply slightly more distance between the two parties:

[*Snooty*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snooty):

> 1:  looking down the nose :  showing disdain
>   2:  characterized by snobbery

[*Uppity*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uppity):

> :  putting on or marked by airs of superiority

Answer (score 0):

*Baby*.

(Babies enjoy, during babyhood, truly being the center of their parents' universe.)

Comment: I like it, I understand it, but I don't think it'd work without the parenthesised context.

Answer (score 0):

How about *Me-Me*? Technically, it doesn't end with a 'y', but in terms of pronunciation, it nearly rhymes with adjectives ending with 'y', like *Cocky*. And it certainly communicates the idea of a writer who is focused on themself.